# Getting two target values from prediction algorithms

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, target, supervised-learning

I have a dataset with sequence tuples and targets like the following:

```
       input_0  input_1 input_2 output
0        0       1.0    2.0      4.0
1        1       2.0    4.0      2.0
2        2       4.0    2.0      4.0
3        4       2.0    4.0      7.0
4        2       4.0    7.0      8.0
```

I have trained algorithms using the output as a target value.

What I want though, is to get the two most possible variables that can occur by one tupple.

For example if i have two tuples for training: `a,b,c,d` and `a,b,c,e` I want to get `d` and `e` as a result with the respective percentage.

Is there something like that possible?

Comment: So you want to group the tuples by the first 3 items, and calculate the frequency of the fourth item per group? Doesn't that basically follow from your description?

Comment: @AmiTavory yes, that's what I need

Comment: So what is your question, exactly?

Comment: @AmiTavory What method should I use to get the two most frequent items? right now I am getting only one by applying the  traditional logic

Comment: Just for explaining this the easiest way, with which languages are you familiar?

Comment: python, java, anything! I will get it @AmiTavory

Comment: Would this happen to be a pandas DataFrame, by any chance?

Comment: @AmiTavory I am using pandas in my implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, this seems to be a pandas.DataFrame. Say you start with

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'input_0': [1, 1, 2, 4, 2], 
    'input_1': [1, 1, 2, 4, 4], 
    'input_2': [2, 2, 2, 4, 7],
    'output': [4, 3, 4, 7, 8]})
>>> df
    input_0 input_1 input_2 output
0   1   1   2   4
1   1   1   2   3
2   2   2   2   4
3   4   4   4   7
4   2   4   7   8
```

Then the following will show the two most common elements per each input tuple, as well as their counts:

```
>>> df.output.groupby([df.input_0, df.input_1, df.input_2]).apply(lambda s: Counter(s).most_common(2)).reset_index()
    input_0 input_1 input_2 output
0   1   1   2   [(3, 1), (4, 1)]
1   2   2   2   [(4, 1)]
2   2   4   7   [(8, 1)]
3   4   4   4   [(7, 1)]
```

Comment: @Kratos Sorry, added missing import.